# under mac terminal: List all of the users whom has at least one running process?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

how to list all of the users whom has at least one running process.

```
The user name should not be duplicated.
The user name should be sorted.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ps xau | cut -f1 -d " "| sort | uniq | tail -n +2
```

You may want to weed out names starting with _ as well like so :

```
ps xau | cut -f1 -d " "| sort | uniq | grep -v ^_ | tail -n +2
```

Comment: appreciate you! that's what I want~~

Comment: this command is also available(with -o user):    ps ax -o user | sort | uniq | grep -v ^_ |  tail -n +2

Answer (score 1):

`users` does what is requested. From the `man` page:

> users lists the login names of the users currently on the system, in
>        sorted order, space separated, on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
w -h  | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq
```

The `w -h` displays all users in system, without header and some output. The `cut` part removes all other information without username. `uniq` ignores duplicate lines.

Comment: The s flag is no longer supported in latest OS X